# Python - import from sibling directory while running as script

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure:

```
PROJECT_DIR
  | --helpers
  |    |--utils.py
  | --stuff
  |    |--script.py
```

I need to run script.py as a script, and from it, I need to use a function from helpers/utils.py.

I tried relative importing `from ..helpers.utils import func`, but it says
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
so I added an empty **init**.py file to each folder, including PROJECT_DIR.
Then I read that while running as a script, the python compiler runs the script as if it was the main module, so it doesn't see any other modules outside so relative import cannot be used.

But what should I do if I need to use that function? It's a fairly simple use case, I can't get my head around why it's so hard to import a function from a file outside the current directory. Tho I'm not really interested in the whys, I'd just like to know a solution how people do this.

Comment: the code in "utils.py" should be in one big function or separate functions.
then you can do something like
"from helpers.utils import functionName"
then call it later in your code like this
"functionName()"
otherwise "any code in the global scope" will be executed after importing the file immediately

Comment: If your pwd is PROJECT_DIR
you can always run module standalone `python -m stuff.script` but remember to have inside the `./helpers` `./stuff` dirs the `__init__.py` files so the are visible for python as packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root_project
└── proj
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── helpers
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── utils.py
    └── stuff
        ├── __init__.py
        └── script.py
```

With this structure just `cd` to `root_project` and use this command:

```
python -m proj.stuff.script
```

Comment: Can the same be done at gitlab ci? Ie, can the runner run a Python script that imports from the util folder without placing the files out to “paths” first?